# What is the answer of this Maths question on surds and quadratic equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0gKk.jpg)

> Integers $a$ and $b$ are such that $(a+3\sqrt{5})^2 + a - b\sqrt{5} = 51$. Find all possible values of $a$ and the corresponding values of $b$.

This is a past paper question, the ms says $a$ has two possible values found via comparison, I do not understand how, please help me to understand this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is meant, here: if you have $c+d\sqrt{5}=51$ with integer $c, d$, you must have $d=0$ (because otherwise, $\sqrt{5}$ would be rational, and thus $c=51$. Now express $c, d$ by $a, b$, and you'll have two equations for those unknowns. So to speak, you compare the coefficients of $1$ and $\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: But can d not be equal to 1/sqrt5 or sqrt5, in both cases we will have a rational number i.e 1 and 5, how do we know that we must equal it to only 0, thanks.

Comment: Because $d$ is an integer. If it is not $0$, you have $\sqrt{5}=(51-c)/d$, a rational number, and that's not possible.